# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'synonyms.yaml'

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I have successfully installed `pyyaml` on my system.

I am using a file of `yaml` that is "`synonyms.yaml`" to replace a word with it synonyms, but i am getting an error of "`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'synonyms.yaml`".

Though I also created the file "synonyms.yaml".

Comment: Pass the complete path of the file in your code. Also, please share the code snippet which is failing.

Comment: That you have installed PyYAML is irrelevant, as that error message comes form Python.